# FROM keyword not found where expected ERROR

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to write an Oracle query for a homework assignment. The assignment is to write one query to return the employee_id, job_id, hire_date and department_id of all employees and a second query listing employee_id, job_id, start_date and department_id from the job_hist table and combine the results as one single output. Make sure you suppress duplicates in the output.

Code I Have:

```
SELECT employee_id AS "Employee ID", job_id AS "Job Id", TO_CHAR(NULL) hire_date "Hire     Date", department_id AS "Department Id",
FROM employees
UNION
SELECT employee_id AS "Employee Id", job_id AS "Job Id", TO_CHAR(NULL) start_date "Start     Date",department_id AS "Department Id", 
FROM job_history;
```

Error I am getting:

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

From what I can tell in the book, the sequence looks right. Any help would be great!

Code after removing the commas:

```
SELECT employee_id AS "Employee ID", job_id AS "Job Id", TO_CHAR(NULL) hire_date "Hire     Date", department_id AS "Department Id"
FROM employees
UNION
SELECT employee_id AS "Employee Id", job_id AS "Job Id", TO_CHAR(NULL) start_date "Start     Date",department_id AS "Department Id" 
FROM job_history;
```

Comment: I will just comment here. There is an extra comma before both `FROM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT employee_id AS "Employee Id", job_id AS "Job Id", TO_CHAR(hire_date,'yyyy-mm-dd') AS "Some date", department_id AS "Department Id"
FROM employees
UNION
SELECT employee_id AS "Employee Id", job_id AS "Job Id", TO_CHAR(start_date,'yyyy-mm-dd') AS "Some date",department_id AS "Department Id"
FROM job_history;
```

Is this working?

Comment: I got a popup box asking me to enter the binding variables?

Comment: @KevinSchultz What happens if you enter something?

Comment: This worked but I had to correct the date format to 'yyyy-mm-dd'. THANKS!

Comment: um `"yyyy-mm-dd"` can't be right, unless you have an identifier called `"yyyy-mm-dd"` for some strange reason.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the comma before FROM keyword ([UNION Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm)).

```
SELECT employee_id AS "Employee ID", 
       job_id AS "Job Id", TO_CHAR(NULL) hire_date "Hire     Date", department_id AS "Department Id"
FROM employees ....
```

Comment: I removed both of the commas and and got the same error. @cctan

Answer (score -1):

```
Select hire_date, employee_id, TO_DATE(null) start_date, 
       job_id, department_id
from employees 
Union
Select TO_DATE(null) hire_date,  employee_id, start_date,
       job_id, department_id
from job_history;
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT employee_id, job_id, hire_date, department_id
FROM employees
UNION ALL
SELECT employee_id, job_id, start_date, department_id
FROM job_history
ORDER BY employee_id

Comment: This question was asked in 2012 and already has an accepted answer.